# NativeDialogRenderer does not seem to be exported from the aurelia-dialog npm package

Tags: dialog, aurelia, aurelia-dialog

Noticed in the docs that native  tags are now supported, however when i try to import the `NativeDialogRenderer` to use in my app configuration it says that it's not a exported member from the aurelia-dialog npm package. My code looks exactly like the example in the docs, with the key diffrence that I'm using TS

I Have made sure i have the latest version of the plugin (2.0.0) and if i look in my `node_modules/aurelia-dialog/types` folder I have another folder called `renderers` and in that I have a `native-dialog-renderer.d.ts` file, I however cannot find a refrence to this file from the `aurelia-dialog.d.ts` file

Is this a problem with the npm package or is it something with my environment? Has anyone else got the `NativeDialogRenderer` to work?